# Is there anywhere in England that might remind someone of Thailand?

Tags: england, thai-citizens

I am trying to make a Thai person feel a bit happier not being able to return to Thailand by finding somewhere in England that will remind them of home.

I can find one Buddhist temple in London, and a load of restaurants but they aren't ideal.

Is there anywhere else that fits the criteria?

Comment: Not an answer per se, but... You have discovered something that's often discussed in Thailand: Thai people are "un-exportable". They are by and large uncomfortable with moving away from Thailand, and are often unhappy away from home and family, even temporarily. There's nothing in England that could make a Thai person happier – the weather, the food, the language, etc...

Comment: @dda I have never heard that before but it is apt for this situation. Unfortunately they can't go home, at least not for a while so I am just trying to do what I can for them.

Comment: Try to find a Thai community.  Our Thai friends feel most at home when talking Thai and eating Thai food with Thai friends.